# React - Recorrer la respuesta de una API

Tags: javascript, html, html5, reactjs, react-native

tengo una api que me devuelve dentro de "data" una serie de objetos, tal como muestro en la captura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo tengo este código con React (disculpar estoy empezando) y no veo como recorrer dentro de data los elementos.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ListItems extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items : [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://api-diets.local/api/diets/user/2')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {

                this.setState({
                    isLoaded:true,
                    items: json,
                })

            });

    }

    render() {

        var {isLoaded, items} = this.state;

        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        else {

            return (

                // <h3>Listado items</h3>

                <div className="App">
                    <ul>
                        {items.map(item => (
                            <li key={item.id}>
                                Name : {item.name}
                            </li>
                            ))};
                    </ul>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Si hago un console.log de response.data, lo que veo es lo siguiente pero no veo los datos que muestro en la captura primera de "id,name,..."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es asignar el arreglo de items que se encuentra en la respuesta y no toda la respuesta. Recuerda que el API responde con un objeto de la siguiente estructura:

```
  { 
    data: [...]
  }
```

Por lo tanto en `componentDidMount` cuando haces el setState necesitas hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
this.setState({
   isLoaded:true,
   items: json.data,
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con tu ejemplo lo ví. Muchas gracias

Comment: Facepalm para mi, excelente visión colega :)

Answer (score 1):

Me parece extraño que te complique, porque de hecho lo estas haciendo en el *render*.

Sólo debes aplicar un `map` para añadir los objetos como quieras

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch('http://api-diets.local/api/diets/user/2')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
         const aux = json.map(x => { return x.name })

         this.setState({
            isLoaded:true,
            items: aux
         })
      });
}
```

Nos comentas si te sirve :)

Comment: Me da fallo ese código, la estructura que devuelve el json es { data } y dentro de "data" estan los objetos. El error que me da es este : ×
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): json.map is not a function